# Run GitHub workflow only when a commit creates a new file

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I would like to make a GitHub workflow that runs some find-and-replace substitutions on *new* files that are committed to the repository.

I can't find where to start because I can't find a [workflow trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) that seems to be able to detect when a new file is committed.

What set up could I use to run the substitutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) GitHub Actions to discover if a file is added in your PR, as an example:

```yaml
- uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
  id: filter
  with:
    # Enable listing of files matching each filter.
    # Paths to files will be available in `${FILTER_NAME}_files` output variable.
    # Paths will be escaped and space-delimited.
    # Output is usable as command-line argument list in Linux shell
    list-files: shell

    # Changed file can be 'added', 'modified', or 'deleted'.
    # By default, the type of change is not considered.
    # Optionally, it's possible to specify it using nested
    # dictionary, where the type of change composes the key.
    # Multiple change types can be specified using `|` as the delimiter.
    filters: |
      added:
        - added: '**'
```

Then run step only in case of adding:

```yaml
- name: Do some stuff on added files
  if: steps.filter.outputs.added == 'true'
  run: |
    for file in ${{ steps.filter.outputs.added_files }}; do
      echo "${file} added"
    done
```

See the [outputs](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#outputs) section for further details.

Comment: Does PR still stand for pull request in your first paragraph? I'm not trying to target pull requests only (in fact, this might be most useful to me to catch direct additions via github's website)